# Why do I get 'Undefined dynamic step' in Cucumber?

Tags: ruby, cucumber, automated-tests

I have following step definitions (just to illustrate my problem):

```
When(/^the calculator is run$/) do
  step %{When xxx the calculator is run xxx}
end

When(/^xxx the calculator is run xxx$/) do
  @output = `ruby calc.rb #{@input}` 
  raise('Command failed!') unless $?.success?
end
```

In my feature file, when I call:

```
When the calculator is run
```

I got the error message:

```
Undefined dynamic step: "When xxx the calculator is run xxx" (Cucumber::UndefinedDynamicStep)
./features/step_definitions/calculator_steps_when.rb:2:in `/^the calculator is run$/'
features/adding.feature:11:in `When the calculator is run'
features/adding.feature:6:in `When the calculator is run'
```

According to the documentation this should work. Initially I had the steps in different files, and thought maybe I had to provide some include directive, but now it happens even when steps are in the same file. What am I missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In this line:

```
  step %{When xxx the calculator is run xxx}
```

Remove the "When" and it should work correctly.

You can check this in the [cucumber docs](https://www.relishapp.com/cucumber/cucumber/docs/defining-steps/nested-steps). The `step` example they give doesn't include the word "When".

Comment: Yes, it works, thanks. I also noticed that if I change 'step' to 'steps' that works too.

So **step %{xxx the calcualtor is run xxx}** or **step "xxx the calculator is run xxx"** or **steps %{When xxx the calcualtor is run xxx}** all work, but one I used does not.

Comment: Thanks - I found if you use `steps` for dynamic table steps, you also _happen_ to need a `When/And/Then` prefix.